# String pattern matching & replacement

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I would like to find all occurrences of a full stop "." followed by a capital letter in a string and have these replaced with a "; ". How do I do this in Mathematica?

e.g.
`string="this is a test.A new sentence here"` -> output

```
"this is a test; A new sentence here"
```

Edit: and also one other pattern matching question - in a string I would like to have every other line occuring before a next line (\n) being deleted - how do I do that one?

e.g.

```
string="this line should be deleted\nthis one not\nbut this one should be deleted too\nthis one not"
```

-> output

```
"this one not\nthis one not"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some variety:

```
StringReplace[string, ("." ~~ char : LetterCharacter /;UpperCaseQ[char]) :> "; " <> char]
```

> "this is a test; A new sentence here"

As for your second question, one way to go about it would be:

```
StringJoin[Riffle[StringSplit[string, "\n"][[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]], "\n"]]
```

> ```
> "this one not
>  this one not"
> ```

```
FullForm[%]
```

> ```
> "this one not\nthis one not"
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and also for the other answer!

Comment: Oh yes and would you also happen to know the answer to the other question I put in my edited post?

Comment: @TomWenseleers it will be better to ask separate question.

Answer (score 5):

```
StringReplace["this is a test.A new sentence here", RegularExpression["\\.([A-Z])"] -> "; $1"]
```

The $1 is needed to carry the capital letter into the returned string or it will be lost.

Comment: Hey, $1 per replacement can get expensive quickly!

Comment: Its a penalty designed to encourage correct punctuation in the first place.

Comment: Talk about cost functions, eh?